# How delete a element of a list and save the original index of deleted element?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want delete some elements of one list equal to a value:
I can do it :

```
List =[1,2,3.....]
List = [x for x in List if x != 2]
```

How can i save the indexs of the deleted elements ?

I want to use this index to delete elements of another list.

Comment: `idx = List.index(2); List.pop(idx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to make a `list` of indices to keep, then use that to strip the elements from both of your `list`s. `itertools` provides a handy [`compress` utility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) to apply the indices to keep quickly:

```
from itertools import compress

tokeep = [x != 2 for x in List]
List = list(compress(List, tokeep))
otherlist = list(compress(otherlist, tokeep))
```

Alternatively (and frankly more clearly) you can just use one loop to strip both inputs; listcomps are fun, but sometimes they're not the way to go.

```
newlist = []
newotherlist = []
for x, y in zip(List, otherlist):
    if x != 2:
        newlist.append(x)
        newotherlist.append(y)
```

which gets the same effect in a single pass. Even if it does feel less overtly clever, it's very clear, which is a good thing; brevity for the sake of brevity that creates complexity is not a win.

---

And now, to contradict that last paragraph, the amusingly overtly clever and brief solution to one-line this:

```
List, otherlist = map(list, zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(List, otherlist) if x != 2]))
```

For the love of sanity, please don't actually use this, I just had to write it for funsies.

Comment: @Mark: It's a placeholder for the other `list` the OP mentions as being the intended use case for knowing what indices are being deleted (they want to know which indices they deleted from `List` so they can delete the same elements of another `list`; I used `otherlist` as a placeholder to demonstrate doing just that).

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage enumerate

```
for index, val in enumerate(List):
  if val == value:
    del List[index]
    break

print(index)
```

Comment: You have the `index` for free from `enumerate`, so don't use `remove` (which just searches for it again), just use `del List[index]` and save the repeated search.

Answer (score -3):

Based on [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```py
list_first = ['d', 'a']
list_second = ['x', 'z']
def remove_from_lists(element):
  index_deleted = list_first.index(element)
  list_first.remove(element)
  list_second.pop(index_deleted)
remove_from_lists('d')
```

Comment: Your own image makes it very clear `remove` returns nothing, so `index_deleted` is always `None`. This doesn't work as intended. You could do `idx = list_first.index(element)`, then follow-up with `del list_first[idx]` and `del list_second[idx]` (there's no need for `pop` when you don't use the result, plain `del` works fine). Post-edit, you should still replace both the `remove` and the `pop` with simple `del`s (the `remove` in particular needlessly rescans the `list` for an item you already know the index of; the `pop` is only mildly worse than `del list_second[index_deleted]`).